# simple php dom parser strange error in my case

Tags: php, dom, simple-html-dom

error msg : https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxddX.png

I try to scrape the content post of this forum https://forum.lowyat.net/topic/3424996 using below code.

```
$rows = $html->find('.post_table');
$array = array();
foreach($rows as $go){
    $post_text = $go->find('.post_td_right > .post_text')->innertext;
    $array[]= array(
        'content'=> $post_text
    );
}

echo json_encode($array);
```

The loop isn't consistent I wonder why. I can get some result but there's an error saying  Trying to get property of non-object, why?

Comment: can you post exact error message

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/4UZIlks.png

Comment: before foreach, `var_dump($rows);` maybe there are nothing inside.

Comment: @RakeshSharma     $post_text = $go->find('.post_td_right > .post_text')->innertext;

Comment: var_dump($rows); and check $go is an object?

Comment: @RakeshSharma yes it's

Comment: @RakeshSharma any idea what's wrong?